# Get HWND of a window i clicked on

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd

I'm making a program, with c++ and winapi, where you can click a button, then select a window and it changes the transparency of that window.

I have no problems of making the window transparent, but i can't get the hwnd of a window.

When I use this function the program just crashes (No errors are being printed to the console).

```
HWND getHWND(HWND self)
{
  HWND found = GetForegroundWindow();
  if(found == self || found == NULL)
    return getHWND(self);
  return found;
}
```

I tried using this, but I don't like it, because the user has only 2 seconds to click on another window. (I'know I could use a bigger delay, but then it might be to much.. so this isn't optimal)

```
HWND getHWND()
{
  Sleep(2000);
  return GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, you have a stack overflow. Just use a simple `while` loop rather than making your function recursive.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually more efficient.

Comment: You're clicking on a window created by some other application and have your own process that is waiting for the foreground window to change?

Answer (score 3):

Don't poll for the active window, especially not with a recursive function.  Just let the OS notify you when a window is clicked.

When the user clicks on your button, you can use [`SetCapture()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture), or a mouse hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa), to direct subsequent mouse clicks to your app even if they are clicking on someone else's window.  When you detect a click, release the capture/hook, and then use [`WindowFromPoint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint) to get the `HWND` at the location of the click.

Comment: I am using HWND handle and I am successfully getting the handle of a specific window but when I Try to display that window only black screen appears.
Can you please tell me what could be the issue and how to solve that.